# How to avoid Scanner from eof and keep him alive

Tags: java

could you tell me is there any solution to keep Scanner alive after ctrl+d (eof)?

I have this

```
static public int getInt(String errorText){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!scan.hasNextInt()){
        scan.next();
        System.out.println(errorText);
    }


    return scan.nextInt();
}
```

And after ctrl+d i get NoSuchElementException

Then i try to section try-catch

```
static public int getInt(String errorText){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!scan.hasNextInt() ){
        try{
            scan.next();

        }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
            System.out.println("Prechwyciłem!");
        }
        System.out.println(errorText);
    }

    return scan.nextInt();
}
```

and after that i get infinity loop

Comment: I believe that ctrl-D causes `Scanner` to consider itself closed.  I don't think there's any way to get more data from `Scanner` once that's happened.  You'd have the same situation if you were reading from a file, you called `close()` on the file handle, and then you expected to be able to read more data from that file handle.

Comment: This isn't a scanner issue, it's an operating-system issue. Once a stream is closed, it's closed.